# Another winapi file permissions C head-scratcher. Why isn't my method working?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, file-io, acl

I'm really scratching my head over how to correctly use the windows api to determine file permissions. I have seen so many posts on this, but I just can't seem to get it right. Specifically, I would like to examine whether a user has read or write permissions for a given file. These are my steps:

(1) Access fully qualified username of the calling client (inc. domain name) with GetUserNameEx; (returns 0 error; user name appears to print out correctly using a cout debug message).

(2) Access the user's SID using LookupAccountName. (I do this twice, the first time for setting the SID and domain buffer sizes -- Returns 122 error on first call and 0 error on second (to be expected)). I assume the SID buffer is correctly set.

(3) Build a trustee with the obtained sid:

```
        TRUSTEE t;
        PTRUSTEE tptr = &t;
        BuildTrusteeWithSid(tptr,&sid[0]);
```

(4) Obtain the DACL:

```
 // following are freed up later using LocalFree (maybe I should use delete?)
 PACL ppDacl = new ACL;
 PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR ppSecurityDescriptor = new SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR;
 std::vector<TCHAR> v(pathString.begin(), pathString.end());
 GetNamedSecurityInfo(&v[0],
                      SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                      READ_CONTROL,
                      NULL,
                      NULL,
                      &ppDacl,
                      NULL,
                      &ppSecurityDescriptor);
```

A simple call

```
 std::cout<<"ACE count: "<<ppDacl->AceCount<<std::endl;
```

then indicates that there are 58 ACEs leading me to assume that the DACL struct is being correctly instantiated (I am further assuming that there are 58 ACEs although I'm not sure how to manually verify this; I'm really not a windows person). However, printing GetLastError() after the GetNamedSecurityInfo call gives me a 122 (i.e. ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) so it appears something is going wrong at this step.

Note that initializing the PACL and PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR as follows:

```
 ACL dacl;
 PACL ppDacl = &dacl;
 SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
 PSECURITY_DESCRIPTO = &sd;
```

rather than new-ing them doesn't seem to correctly fill the DACL (at least the call

```
  std::cout<<"ACE count: "<<ppDacl->AceCount<<std::endl;
```

reports 0 rather than 58). I'm not sure why.

(5) Finally, I attempt to get the file's access mask given the created trustee and dacl:

```
 ACCESS_MASK access;
 GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(ppDacl, tptr, &access);
```

Which indicates no access rights when I do:

```
 ((access & GENERIC_WRITE)==GENERIC_WRITE)
```

or

```
 ((access & GENERIC_READ)==GENERIC_READ)
```

I hope one of you can shed some light on this

Cheers,

Ben.

Comment: Isn't `std::vector<TCHAR> v` missing the the 0-termination?

Comment: Ah, I assumed it would include it when copying across using the pathString (string) iterator. So I guess I could add v.push_back('\0') after the assignment (right?)

Comment: Could you post a complete piece of code demonstrating the problem?  (Preferably just using a constant string for the filename, to eliminate any unnecessary potential issues.)

Comment: GetLastError() is irrelevant for this function; its return code will indicate what error (if any) occurred.

Comment: Harry -- will aim to post some up soon. @Luke, my apologies but your comment makes no sense to me. Could you clarify?

Comment: The return value of GetNamedSecurityInfo() indicates if an error occurred, not GetLastError().

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is a nonzero error code".  As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Use the `icacls` command to check what the actual permissions are.  Fifty-eight ACEs is possible but unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `GetNamedSecurityInfo()` shall have `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION` set in the set of flags being passed as 3rd parameter. Only then the data being referenced by the value returned in the 6th parameter will be valid after the call returned.

Verbatim from `GetNamedSecurityInfo()`'s [documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> ppDacl [out, optional]
>
> ... 
>   The returned pointer is valid only if you set the DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION flag.

---

Also as a side note: There is no need to initialise `ppDacl` and `ppSecurityDescriptor` as this is done by `GetNamedSecurityInfo()`. If you dynamically allocate memory to those this causes a memory leak, as by the call to `GetNamedSecurityInfo()` you lose the references to what you allocated.

Comment: Alk, many thanks. I have made the changes you suggested, removing the initializations and changing the 3rd parameter in GetNameSecurityInfo to READ_CONTROL | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION. I am now getting an error 1008 (An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist). Any idea? Cheers.

Comment: This might due to the missing 0-termination as mentioned in my other comment to the OP. @BenJ

Comment: Well, I added v.push_back('\0') and I'm still getting the same error.. all these error codes..

Comment: So how do you assign `pathString` though, with which value? @BenJ

Comment: pathString is a boost::filesystem::path.string(). I.e. pathString = tstring(bp.string()) where bp is a boost path and tstring is a typedef'ed std::wstring or std::string depending on whether compilation is unicode (in which case wstring is used) or ansi (in which case string is used).

Comment: For the 3rd parameter to be passed to `GetNamedSecurityInfo()`, `READ_CONTROL` is not a valid value, so just pass `DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION`.  @BenJ

Comment: From the error I conclude the functions is passed a name referring a non-existing file. @BenJ

Comment: Hmmm, I very much doubt that this is the case. I have multiple tests to verify the file's existence. As far as I can tell, its definitely there..

Comment: You are right, it would return error 2 or 3 then. Just another guess: your rights are sufficient to actually perform what you want? Did you try running the code as local admin? @BenJ